# MSSQL 2008 - select only rows where column has unique values never duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need select not duplicted values, which never has been duplicated, use distinct is not solution.
I need show more fields from row than one, which is used to grouping.

My query which show only one field:

```
SELECT NIPL
FROM KONTRAHENT  GROUP BY NIPL HAVING (COUNT(NIPL)=1) 
ORDER BY NIPL DESC
```

Table:

```
id | NIPL
 1 | 230
 2 | 450   <- I want to select only this row
 3 | 230
 3 | 123
 4 | 123
```

Now my select return only NIPL. Simple adding id to statment is not woking. After long googling i'm give up. I need yours help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a subquery.

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM KONTRAHENT
WHERE NIPL IN 
(
   SELECT NIPL
   FROM KONTRAHENT
   GROUP BY NIPL
   HAVING COUNT(NIPL)=1 
)
ORDER BY NIPL DESC
```

Or this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM KONTRAHENT
JOIN 
(
   SELECT NIPL
   FROM KONTRAHENT
   GROUP BY NIPL
   HAVING COUNT(NIPL)=1 
) AS SUB ON KONTRAHENT.NIPL = SUB.NIPL
ORDER BY KONTRAHENT.NIPL DESC
```

Or (in systems that allow CTEs) this:

```
WITH SUB AS
(
   SELECT NIPL
   FROM KONTRAHENT
   GROUP BY NIPL
   HAVING COUNT(NIPL)=1 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM KONTRAHENT
JOIN SUB ON KONTRAHENT.NIPL = SUB.NIPL
ORDER BY KONTRAHENT.NIPL DESC
```